# WordPress Add Media button of WP_Editor on custom role profile page in the front-end not working

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, user-roles, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have a custom role defined which has a separate profile page in the front-end. In the profile page there is a wp_editor with Add Media button. But the image is not being attached. This is the error seen  when uploading the image - **Sorry, you are not allowed to attach files to this post.**

This is the capability of the custom role:

```
$admins = get_role( 'trip_vendor' );
$admins->add_cap( 'upload_files' );
$admins->add_cap( 'level_1' );
$admins->add_cap( 'edit_post' );                                                   
$admins->add_cap( 'edit_posts' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'edit_other_posts' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'publish_posts' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'read_post' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'read_private_posts' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'delete_post' );
$admins->add_cap( 'can_edit_posts' );
```

This is how the custom role is logged in with ajax:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $creds = array();
        $creds['user_login'] = $user;
        $creds['user_password'] = $pass;
        $creds['remember'] = true;
        $user = wp_signon( $creds, is_ssl() );
        if ( is_wp_error($user) ) 
        {
          $result['type'] = 'failed';
          $result['message'] = __( 'Incorrect Login Credentials!.', 'wp-travel-engine' );
            if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )
            {
               $result = json_encode($result);
               echo $result;
            }
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['login'] = 'login';
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
            $result['type'] = 'success';
            $result['message'] = __( 'Logging In...', 'wp-travel-engine' );
            if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )
            {
                $result = json_encode($result);
                echo $result;
            }
        }
```

Can someone please provide some guidelines on this?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: If I login wp-admin from that custom role and try to upload in the front-end then the error is not seen. However, if I login from front, the error seen is **Sorry, you are not allowed to attach files to this post.**

Comment: I believe `edit_posts` is the capability it needs. Sounds like the problem may lie in the frontend login function. You could test if it's definitely doing the check for the user you intend, and that is has the right capabilities: `var_dump(wp_get_current_user());`

Answer (score 0):

Add `$admins->add_cap( 'upload_files' );`

This will enable a user to upload files as well.